# How to check if the value is not null and if not then the value should be displayed in Textbox in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008

This is my code

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs);
        con.Open();
        string query = "select Name from t_identities where Branchid = '" + branchidtext.Text + "' and Accountid = '" + accountidtext.Text + "'";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
        string value = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();

        if (value != null)
        {
            nametext.Text = value.ToString();
        }

        else
        {
            nametext.Text = "No records Found";
        }

    }
```

If the query returs Null then the textbox should return No records found or else it should display the name generated by the query in the text box. Please help.

Comment: the code you posted is working fine or not? what else you are expecting from it ?

Comment: It gives an error if no rows are fetched from the query.

Comment: and what is the error ? and on what line it shows the error ?

Comment: string value = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();(Error Line)------Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are getting error in this line

```
string value = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
```

as it trying to convert a null value to string. Better use `Convert.ToString(cmd.ExecuteScalar())` to handle this case.

Your if/else block is ok

Answer (score 0):

SQL's `null` maps to C#'s `DBNull.Value`:

```
var value = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
if (value != DBNull.Value)
{
    nametext.Text  = (string)value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

substitute

```
string value = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
```

with

```
object value = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
string value = "";
if ( (value = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString())!= null)
{
 nametext.Text=value.ToString();
}
```

Comment: this will still throw exception, when cmd.ExecuteScalar() is null

Comment: Nitn, I have tested it, it wont throw any exception, please try to implement it before you can claim that

Comment: What happens when cmd.ExecuteScalar() is null

Comment: I use this technique since a few years, I used try catch blocks, but just as I saw ur comment I thought I should test it without try catch, so I did it, and it is giving no exception, it will just move next

Comment: Yep, Actually ExceuteScalar return int value, please edit answer so that i can revert downvote:)